# Node JS + Put request does not has body

Tags: node.js, api, atom-editor, put

I start exploring NodeJS and working on API's sample. I am able to get `req.body` in post request and it is working fine but when i create function to put, my `req.body` come empty like `{}`. 
My code as below:

Post request which is working:

```
router.post('/',  function(req, res) {
   const name = req.body.username
   const address = req.body.address
   const phone = req.body.phone
   const values = [name, address, phone]
   const sql = "INSERT INTO userInfo (username, address, phone) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
   res.locals.connection.query(sql, values, function (error, results, fields) {
            if(error){
                res.send(JSON.stringify({"status": 500, "error": error, "response": null}));
            } else {
                const value = {"status":"success", "userId": results.insertId}
                res.send(JSON.stringify({"status": 200, "error": null, "response": value}));
            }
        });
});
```

My put request which is not working:

```
router.put('/',  function(req, res) {
   const userId = req.body.userId
   const name = req.body.username
   const address = req.body.address
   const phone = req.body.phone
   const values = [name, address, phone, userId]
   console.log(req.body);
   const sql = "UPDATE userInfo set username =?, address = ?, phone = ?  WHERE userId = ?";
   res.locals.connection.query(sql, values, function (error, results, fields) {
            if(error){
                res.send(JSON.stringify({"status": 500, "error": error, "response": null}));
            } else {
                const value = {"status":"success", "userId": results.insertId}
                res.send(JSON.stringify({"status": 200, "error": null, "response": value}));
            }
        });
});
```

Please suggest me, what is wrong in that and how can i get req.body.

Answer (score 0):

For update functionality, I also faced the same problem when I was working on APIs. Kept scratching my head to find the problem for two days. Eventually, I used the post function and it worked for me.

Just use `router.post` instead of `router.put`.

Comment: Yes, it will work but want to explore, why is it not working?

Comment: Well actually, the widely accepted notion that POST is for used creating data and PUT is to update is not quite right. 
It is better to use PUT for creating and POST for updating. 
See this, 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2691891/10086490

Comment: To confirm this, you should try the other way around and see it work.

Comment: using a body parser as a middleware worked....

Answer (score 0):

Verify bodyParser in your app.js file.
If it contains only "bodyParser.json":

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

you'll get an empty body unless you use "application/json" content type.
For: "text/plain"
use:

```
app.use(bodyParser.text());
```